# Deleting a User record from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We've some test data inside our production database and I'm trying to clean it up.

I was removing some test email addresses from the console directly.

```
User.where(:email=>"asdf@example.com").first.delete
```

This deleted that record.

Now when I'm trying to create another account with this same email address it says  email is already taken.

I've done this several times in my dev environment, and it has worked like a charm.

I know I should never directly remove a record in prod from console, but this is an one-off scenario and I'm just curious why it is not working.

Please help me with this.

Comment: dup record? or try `reload!`ing console

Comment: Hey Nithin. Thanks for the response. There is no duplicate record. I've tried reloading the console several times. That didn't work. It has got something to do with the way device creates user records, that I'm clearly missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using something like the [Paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) gem in production to soft-delete User records? If so, try `User.with_deleted.where(:email=>"asdf@example.com")` and if that returns a result just change the user's email address to a non-existent one.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this in console**

```
User.where(:email => "asdf@example.com").delete_all
```

Or if u want to delete all data

```
u = User.find("someone@example.com")
u.delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting only first record of your User table as per your command:

```
User.where(:email=>"asdf@example.com").first.delete
```

I think, there are multiple entries are there.!

You should to use delete_all with User object like below:

```
User.where(:email=>"asdf@example.com").delete_all
```

Comment: Can you try with try with select option like User.select(:name => 'pravin').delete_all ?

Comment: The record is already deleted from the the DB. User.selec doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.where(:email=>"asdf@example.com").delete_all
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time for the operation with console you have to reload the console and the insert the record new one.

And one more thing, you are using first user with email so in you user model there should be some validation with email with uniq.